# JBL Bluetooth headset sounds bad on Windows 10 when using it with Skype

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, skype, headphones, headset

I have problems using a JBL TUNE 500BT bluetooth headset with Windows 10. The headset works fine with my phone but not working with Windows 10.

After searching the net all solutions are talking about disabling the 'Handsfree Telephony' option which will disables the mic but I want to use the headset with Skype and communication apps.

The problem happens when I open Skype the sound goes aways (or sounds very bad with crackling) but the mic works.

All settings are set properly in Skype and sound in control panel. All drivers are up to date (bluetooth adapter, JBL headset).

As I understood from the searching the internet it is common problem with bluetooth headsets with Windows.

Is there any solution for this without disabling the mic?

Comment: What happens if you test this in another app that is not skype, and just play audio? Is it also bad?

Comment: playing audio is fine (with some crackling). it goes into the stereo mode. but doesn't work with any communication app when it tries to go into hands free mode. but if I disabled handsfree telephony the stereo works without any crackling

Comment: And that's exactly how it is. You don't need to disable one of the profiles. You should be able to toggle hi-fi stereo (without mic) and mono+mic. But you can't have both. Not a problem, it's how it has been designed and all Bluetooth headphones work this way, for now.

Answer (score 15):

After doing some digging I saw someone mention setting something on the output, but wasn't clear. After playing around with the controls, I found out that (In Windows 10) you have to go into *Sound settings*, and click *Manage sound devices*.

From here you'll see that input has the hands-free (as it should) but output has both stereo and hands-free. you will need to disable specifically the hands free from the output devices.

After I did this, I tested (and confirmed working) the mic and the audio at the same time. If you don't want to use the mic, simply disable the hands-free connection from the *Sound* control panel.

Comment: Exactly the opposite helped me, I disabled the "stereo" device, and selected both for mic and speaker the "hands free" and for the first time it was distorted, then by playing with the volume it suddenly fixed.

Comment: @karatedog, I have the same problem. Could you please add more detail about your fix? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! you saved my life

Comment: Disabled hands-free and input and works like charm!

Comment: I think @karatedog has it correct.  At least for bluetooth earpiece type headphone/handsfree/whatever gizmo's.  grrr.