# Why don’t wireless gaming headsets have bad audio when the mic is connected?

Tags: audio, drivers, bluetooth, microphone, headset

I recently just received as a gift a JBL Tune205BT. For my surprise, I discovered the world of problems that comes with headset bluetooth devices on Windows 10: When the bluetooth is connected, Windows makes available two audio input devices. One is the Stereo option and another is the Headset (Hands Free AG Audio). Here are some links that explain the problem and people that have the same problem as me:

- “[Why Bluetooth Headsets Are Terrible on Windows PCs](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/)”
- [JBL Bluetooth headset sounds bad on Windows 10 when using it with Skype](https://superuser.com/questions/1471581/jbl-bluetooth-headset-sounds-bad-on-windows-10-when-using-it-with-skype/)
- “[Bluetooth problemas com headphone - Windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-problemas-com-headphone-windows-10/211c8a7e-b7b5-41be-8956-13de82d29d18?page=1)”
- “[Problemas entre o Fone JBL TUNE 600BTNC e o Windows 10](https://comunidade.tecnoblog.net/t/problemas-entre-o-fone-jbl-tune-600btnc-e-o-windows-10/7260/4)”

I don't own a gaming headset (Corsair, Razer, etc) but why these wireless headsets doesn't have this problem? As I said, I do not own a gaming headset and I don't have 100% sure that they don't have this problem, but I looked up on the internet and haven't found nothing about it. Also, no one would buy a gaming headset that has a crap audio when the mic is turned on.

[image: Input devices]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically gaming headsets sidestep the problem by not using Bluetooth at all. They will use a proprietary low latency audio transmission method which is the main reason they come with their own USB dongles.

While some *might* additionally support Bluetooth in order to be connected to a phone, almost all "low latency" headsets will not list Bluetooth support at all. They will instead simply state "2.4GHz radio" or something similar.

2.4GHz is the free band used by Bluetooth and WiFi but is not limited to just those two things.

Not using Bluetooth also gets away from the awful lag associated with it, which has long made it borderline useless for gaming.

Before you say "but PlayStation and xbox controllers" both the console and controllers were designed that way from the ground up to work together.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You're right, I did some searching and none list Bluetooth at their hotsites, which at first I thought strange, but you explain the reason. And also, I have the Xbox One controller to play on my PC and had to buy the wireless adapter, they really don't work with bluetooth. Thank you!