# no sound through bluetooth headset -- only mic is working

Tags: audio, drivers, bluetooth, control-panel, microsoft-surface-3

Skype echo tests work fine using the Bluetooth Plantronics `PLT V5200` earpiece mic and speaker.

Using textnow, I get a series of beeps on the earpiece indicating that the call is being made.  The phone can hear from the Plantronics mic.

However, the Plantronics headset earpiece hears nothing from the phone.

Is it odd that there are two Plantronics devices listed in the control panel below?

[image: settings bluetooth]

[image: control]

[image: devmgmt]

Perhaps it's a privacy setting?  It seems that the bluetooth headset works fine ***until*** a call (zoom/whatever) is initiated, then a switch is flipped.

Perhaps this is application specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand:

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]

but it seems to work...for now...

I'll have to check zoom/skype/teams/etc/etc

with reference to:

https://superuser.com/a/1503368/977796

I don't think it's duplicate, exactly.