# "I understand that you're experiencing an issue with PC audio. May I run a quick scan to try to find a solution?" instead of a volume adjustment

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-3

I just want to adjust the volume, so clicked on the speaker icon which results in:

[image: sound]

seems a bit excessive.  Last I [recall](https://superuser.com/q/1646066/977796), the volume could be adjusted either with the "rocker" switch or through the speaker icon itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to adjust the volume, so clicked on the speaker icon which results in:
>
> [image: sound]

You accidentally clicked on "Troubleshoot sound problems".

[image]