# Can only select "Troubleshoot Sound Problems" but cannot adjust the volume

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-3

To [clarify and narrow](https://superuser.com/q/1661702/977796) a previous question, why does the rocker switch to adjust the volume suddenly no longer work?  Assuming this is related to an inability to select sound settings from the taskbar.

**Why is it not possible to adjust the volume by clicking the speaker icon on the taskbar?**

While its possible that the volume switch failed at the same time, this seems unlikely.  More likely is that this a symptom for a common root cause.

While it's possible that I've accidentally clicked on "troubleshoot" that's also unlikely.  More likely is that this is a symptom for a common root cause.

Why might it not be possible to adjust the volume from either the rocker button on the tablet, or by clicking the "volume" icon from the taskbar?

device manager screenshot:

[image: bluetooth_device_manager_image]

As I now recall, and pardon for not mentioning, I've disabled some audio devices in order to get bluetooth working with zoom.

Comment: The red X means no sound devices were detected. Please provide a screenshot of Device Manager with the sound category (if present) expanded.

Comment: Looks fine to me, though you currently have a Bluetooth headset connected. Please expand the “Audio inputs and outputs” category too, it is the most important. // I suggest you re-enable all audio devices you disabled. There is no need to disable devices to use a BT headset with Zoom.

Comment: as you suggested @DanielB I went ahead and enabled the hardware, bluetooth seems to still work and now the volume seems to work.