# why would the firewall seemingly have disabled speakers on a surface 3?

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, firewall, microsoft-surface

Suddenly the Windows firewall detected Zoom and seems to have disabled sound -- although the mic from the USB headset was audible to the other person.

I'll have to update this after going through all possible settings, but it's just a [forever](https://superuser.com/q/1661932/977796) problem with sound on tablets seemingly.

I unplugged the headset, still couldn't get sound.  On the USB headset, adjusting volume caused the volume indicator icon to go change accordingly.

This happened immediately after windows defender asked whether to allow zoom (to which I said yes).

It's a surface 3, but:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfacepro-surfver_surfpro7-surftop_sound/no-audio-for-surface-pro7-on-zoom-meetings/ae05e5de-b15b-43b3-b763-cabbe887ca13

Comment: *why would the firewall seemingly have disabled speakers*, that one is easy. **It wouldn't have.**

Comment: thanks @user1292580 so then I'll look into it further.

Comment: Try the troubleshooter in *Settings - Update and Security - Troubleshoot* (you can also right click speaker - *Troubleshoot Sound Problems*). Also on the right click review settings of *Sound Settings* and also *Volume Mixer* (with Zoom running).

Comment: Have you rebooted Windows?