# How to set up headset to work properly with bluetooth dongle?

Tags: bluetooth, microphone, headphones, headset

I recently bought JBL Tune 750BTNC and tp-link ub400 bluetooth adapter. Unfortunately when I try to use it to communicate on Microsoft Teams, Skype or Zoom sound is really bad.
There are two modes of operation of JBL Tune, one is Headphones(Stereo) and another one is Headset(Hands-free). When I use Stereo mode with mic on my camera everything works fine, but if I want to use mic on my JBL sound gets really bad. I am pretty sure that the problem is with hands-free mode because if I try to use it for watching something on Youtube sound is much worst then with stereo. I tried many combinations of this too modes(enabled hands-free, disabled stereo and vise versa) but nothing works.
I also tried everything that is stated in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1471581/jbl-bluetooth-headset-sounds-bad-on-windows-10-when-using-it-with-skype)(although is pretty much the same thing I tried) but it didn't work.

Does anyone know the solution to the problem? Do I need to buy a better bluetooth dongle, do I need to do some insane settings config?

Also the operating system is Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Bluetooth 4.2 doesn't support high-quality audio when there's also a microphone active at the same time.<sup>[1](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/)</sup> What basically happens is that the bandwidth available gets cut in half for both audio-in and audio-out, which results in the huge drop in sound quality.

There is no real solution for this problem as it is a hardware limitation. There's the aptX codec that some high-end headsets use, which uses compression to boost the quality a bit, but the JBL Tune 750BTNC doesn't have this.